# Problems with sql query using rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

My problem is that the query that I put below, used in DbBrowser for Sqlite on my PC, returns the data correctly. But once executed in the application it does not show me all the data I am missing what results from the UNION SELECT, it is as if I only solved the first part before UNION

```
val parametro_lista_seleccionada: Array<String> =
        arrayOf(lista_seleccionada.toString()) //Creamos un array con el id de la lista seleccionada para pasarla como parametro al SELECT
val cursor_consulta_sql: Cursor = bd_conexion.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contenido_lista AS cl, productos AS p WHERE cl.id_lista = ? AND cl.id_producto = p.id_producto UNION SELECT * FROM contenido_lista AS cl, productos_manuales AS pm WHERE cl.id_lista = ? AND cl.id_producto = pm.id_producto ORDER BY p.id_seccion,pm.id_seccion" ,parametro_lista_seleccionada)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that both unioned queries return the same number of columns, since you don't get any errors.

You should use proper `JOIN` syntax with an `ON` clause and not this archaic syntax with the comma.

Also, the `ORDER BY` clause when used at the end of `UNION`, it is applied to the result of the `UNION` and not to any of the the participating queries.
So you can't use the aliases of the tables that you have previously set, to the columns after `ORDER BY`.

Finally, in your query there are 2 `?` placeholders, so you must pass as the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` an array of 2 strings. I guess it's the same string, but you must use it twice in the array.

So change to this:

```
val parametro_lista_seleccionada = arrayOf(lista_seleccionada.toString(), lista_seleccionada.toString())
val cursor_consulta_sql: Cursor = bd_conexion.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM contenido_lista AS cl INNER JOIN productos AS p " + 
    "ON cl.id_producto = p.id_producto " + 
    "WHERE cl.id_lista = ? " + 
    "UNION " + 
    "SELECT * " + 
    "FROM contenido_lista AS cl INNER JOIN productos_manuales AS pm " + 
    "ON cl.id_producto = pm.id_producto " + 
    "WHERE cl.id_lista = ? " + 
    "ORDER BY id_seccion" ,
    parametro_lista_seleccionada
)
```

Just by the name of `lista_seleccionada`, I will make a guess, maybe it is not a string. Is it a list? 
If so then `lista_seleccionada.toString()` will not return 2 strings, but 1 string which is a comma separated list of the strings.
So change to:

```
val parametro_lista_seleccionada = arrayOf(lista_seleccionada[0], lista_seleccionada[1])
```

or if the items of the list are numbers:

```
val parametro_lista_seleccionada = arrayOf(
    lista_seleccionada[0].toString(), 
    lista_seleccionada[1]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed. Now everything works correctly.